# Unable to evaluate the expression

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

[image]

[image: enter link description here]

I'm unable to debug the the `SaveFileToDisk` method. Please me help me out how to resolve the issue. Thanks in advance.

```
private void Download_TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        PortalTeacherDairyAttachmentList attachment = ((TappedEventArgs)e).Parameter as PortalTeacherDairyAttachmentList;
        byte[] attachmentbyte = attachment.Attachment;
   
        DependencyService.Get<IDownloadManager>().SaveFileToDisk(attachment.FileName,attachmentbyte);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }
}
```

SaveFileToDiskCode:

```
        {
            Toast.MakeText(Android.App.Application.Context, "Downloading started...", ToastLength.Long).Show();
            var dir = Android.OS.Environment.GetExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Android.OS.Environment.DirectoryDownloads);
            var absolutepath = dir.AbsolutePath;
            string name = filename;
            string filePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(absolutepath, name);
            try
            {
                System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(filePath, data);
                var mediaScanIntent = new Intent(Intent.ActionMediaScannerScanFile);
                mediaScanIntent.SetData(Uri.FromFile(new File(filePath)));
                Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Context.SendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent);
                OpenFile(filePath, filename);

                Toast.MakeText(Android.App.Application.Context, "File downloaded at" + filePath, ToastLength.Long).Show();
                CreateNotificationChannel(name);
            }
            catch (System.Exception e)
            {
                System.Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
                Toast.MakeText(Android.App.Application.Context, "Error occured", ToastLength.Long).Show();
            }
        }
```

Comment: As I can see the attachmentbyte is null. I suppose the attachment.Attachment is null too. Can you provide more details about variables you are using?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/oDols.png. The attached variables im using. SaveFileToDisk implementation here

Comment: If `SaveFileToDisk` is a method, you can't debug it by adding it as a Watch. If you have a breakpoint on the invocation of SaveFileToDisk, but the DependencyService does not resolve an `IDownloadManager`, you also won't be able to debug the method. Can you provide more details about the steps you've taken to attempt to debug the method?